# If else refactoring witth contains logic

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My goal is to refactor the conditions below in more proper form. It would be great to replace these conditions with something better.

The main idea of that logic that order of these "ifs" should not be changed. Namely if at least one "j" value exist in array it should be returned even if other values exist.

```
var items = [j,a];
if(_.contains(items, "j")) {
    return "j";
} else if(_.contains(items, "a")) {
    return "a";
} else if(_.contains(items, "l")) {
    return "l";
}
return "d";
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: this might fit better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Is this the "something better" you were looking for? (notice the order of the letters is backwards, that way if j is contained it will be the letter returned...)

```
var items = [j,a];
var matchItems = ["l",  "a", "j"];
var letter = "d"; //default

_.each(matchItems, function(item) {
   if(_.contains(items, item)) letter = item;
})

return letter
```

**Update: use this if you want to keep the breaking condition**

```
var items = [j,a];
var matchItems = ["j", "a", "l"];
var letter = "d"; //default

matchItems.every(function(item) {
    if(_.contains(items, item)) {
        letter = item;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});

return letter;
```

Comment: this will be slower because there is no break condition - maybe not an issue if there are only a few items included per list

Comment: @Wolfgang fair enough updated...

Answer (score 0):

Below are a few variations. I wouldn't say that any of them is a *more proper form* or a *better* one, though. (Unless your definition of 'better' happens to match something in there.)

```js
// PROS: rather short
// CONS: not efficient (the full intersection is computed)
function test(items) {
  var res = _.first(_.intersection(items, ['j', 'a', 'l']));
  return res === undefined ? 'd' : res;
}

console.log(test(['j', 'a']));
console.log(test(['x', 'y']));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

```js
// This one is close to WalkAways's 2nd method
// PROS: rather short and rather efficient
// CONS: slightly less readable
function test(items) {
  var res = _.find(['j', 'a', 'l'], function(c) { return _.contains(items, c); });
  return res === undefined ? 'd' : res;
}

console.log(test(['j', 'a']));
console.log(test(['x', 'y']));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

```js
// PROS: Jedi trick!
// CONS: Jedi trick. Not very readable and inappropriate for a longer list.
function test(items) {
  return "djal"[
    _.contains(items, "j") && 1 ||
    _.contains(items, "a") && 2 ||
    _.contains(items, "l") && 3 || 0
  ];
}

console.log(test(['j', 'a']));
console.log(test(['x', 'y']));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

As a side note, another simple way to improve the readability of your original code might be to remove the useless `else` statements:

```
if(_.contains(items, "j")) return "j";
if(_.contains(items, "a")) return "a";
if(_.contains(items, "l")) return "l";
return "d";
```

(Personally, I would probably keep the braces rather than put the `if` and `return` statements on the same row. But this is a matter of taste.)